# How to customize autocomplete dropdown with html/css?

Tags: html, css

I have a input field:

```
<input class="text-field__input" type="text" id="user-subject" name="user-subject" placeholder="Subject" required="" aria-label="Enter your Subject">
```

It has a monospace font. I click with the cursor on this input (Chrome browser), and get a list with hints. But hints haves another font:

[image]

And when I hover on one hint, it autocompletes the field with another font:

[image]

But when I select this option, text that autocomplete the field become monospace:

[image]

Is there some option to change a font for autocomplete?

Comment: Are these autocomplete hints something in your code, or native browser functionality?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates?

Comment: You can check  this blog (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/)

Answer (score 0):

the styling of auto complete dropdown list is ultimatly up to the browser. however you can try to use the pseudo element `::part`to style the shadow DOM. however note that this doesn't work with all browser especially old one. as the styling of auto complete lists is up to the browser.